# Reference request for non-commutative analogues of exterior algebras

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

I am reading Combinatorial Group Theory In Homotopy Theory I by Fred Cohen ([preprint available on web page](http://www.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/cohf/)). Here is an extract of the paper:

[image]

Cohen called $A^R_n$ "**a standard tool used in combinatorial group theory ...**" but I have not read about this non-commutative analogue of exterior algebras anywhere else. Besides Cohens paper, is there any other reference to this algebra? I will be interested in the special case when $R=\mathbb{Z}$; if there is any reference on this algebra and in particular the automorphism group $\mathrm{Aut}(A^\mathbb{Z}_n)$ it would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cohen has already discussed such noncommutative analogues of exterior algebras much earlier, e.g., in the book [Handbook of Algebraic Topology](https://books.google.at/books?id=xoM5DxQZihQC&pg=PA1204&lpg=PA1204&dq=non-commutative+analogues+of+exterior+algebras&source=bl&ots=pyF9cIOpBf&sig=kBNj5Nh0k8aiEKJ9CyG-0hutGDA&hl=de&sa=X&ei=_6yJVMLNIMKN7Aac04HoAg&ved=0CHAQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=non-commutative%20analogues%20of%20exterior%20algebras&f=false) from  $1995$, see the section before Theorem $13.1$. Note that this reference is not cited in Cohen's preprint "Combinatorial Group Theory In Homotopy Theory I".

Another reference is the paper [Natural transformations of tensor algebras and representations of combinatorial groups](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0602218) by Grbic, and Wu;
but again this is based on Cohen's definition.

Comment: Thank you for the reference! Is it really (as Cohen said) a standard tool in combinatorial group theory? I seldom see it except in some papers by a few algebraic topologists such as F.R. Cohen and J. Wu.

Comment: This depends on the interpretation of the term "combinatorial group theory", which is rather general.

Comment: So can I assume that this algebra is not found in most (all) text books on combinatorial group theory?

Comment: You can check this yourself in the literature. For example, look at the "Recommended Literature" on combinatorial group theory [here](https://people.kth.se/~tatiana/5B1459/).

Comment: Many thanks again for your kind assistance!!